# Bubble charts Vaadin: how can i set the axes origin on coordinates 0,0

Tags: charts, vaadin, vaadin7, axes, vaadin8

Now vaadin set X axis on min vertical value(bottom) and Y axis on min horizontal value (left), but i will like set axes on middle

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that axis are always in left and bottom of the plot area.
One thing you can do is set the min at negative, or leave it automatic, and add a plotline with value 0 for both axes. That way you can visualize the chart's quadrants.

If you're using java API you can use [addPlotLine](https://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin/vaadin-charts-flow/6.2.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/charts/model/XAxis.html#addPlotLine-com.vaadin.flow.component.charts.model.PlotLine-) method in xAxis or yAxis classes. You can check the java tab in the [boxplot demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/charts/BoxPlot)